# bower install fails giving me EACCES: permission denied error

Tags: macos, npm, bower

I get the following error below when running `npm install -g bower`.

Node version v6.2.0
npm version 3.9.3
OSX Yosemite

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/XXX/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Reference:

[Github - EACCES: permission denied (closed issue)](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262)

Comment: and how to change this dir? It might be undesirable or imporrible to write/read this dir